# C# XML Parsing- find position of an element and read next elements

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Hi I have a sample xml as follows

```
<ROOTELEMENT>
<RECORDSET>
    <ROW><VALUE>AAA</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>0</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>00</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>BBB</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>1</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>2</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>CCC</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>3</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>30</VALUE></ROW>
</RECORDSET>
<RECORDSET>
    <ROW><VALUE>DDD</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>4</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>40</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>EEE</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>5</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>6</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>FFF</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>7</VALUE></ROW>
    <ROW><VALUE>70</VALUE></ROW>
</RECORDSET>
 </ROOTELEMENT>
```

I have to get the position of particular ROW with some VALUE. After that, I have to read the VALUE of a speicifed number of ROWs from that position onwards.
Ex: If i give some value as 'BBB', for this i have to get the next two values '1' and '2'.If i give some value as 'FFF', for this i have to get the next two values  '7' and '70'.
I am using .Net framework2.0. I can not use LINQ. Please help me.

Comment: Show us the code you have tried for this.

Comment: Give my answer a shot.  Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below. It iterates through the nodes and stores the values you expect in `foundValues`

```
string valueToFind = "FFF";
string xml = @"<ROOTELEMENT>
                <RECORDSET>
                    <ROW><VALUE>AAA</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>0</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>00</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>BBB</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>1</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>2</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>CCC</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>3</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>30</VALUE></ROW>
                </RECORDSET>
                <RECORDSET>
                    <ROW><VALUE>DDD</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>4</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>40</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>EEE</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>5</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>6</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>FFF</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>7</VALUE></ROW>
                    <ROW><VALUE>70</VALUE></ROW>
                </RECORDSET>
                 </ROOTELEMENT>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

int count = 0;
List<string> foundValues = new List<string>();
foreach (XmlNode root in doc.ChildNodes)
    foreach (XmlNode recorset in root.ChildNodes)
        foreach (XmlNode row in recorset.ChildNodes)
            foreach (XmlNode value in row.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (value.InnerText == valueToFind || count == 1 || count == 2)
                {
                    if (count == 1 || count == 2)
                        foundValues.Add(value.InnerText);
                    count++;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but here is a Linq to XML alternative:

```
private static string getXML()
{
    return @"<ROOTELEMENT>
                    <RECORDSET>
                        <ROW><VALUE>AAA</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>0</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>00</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>BBB</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>1</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>2</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>CCC</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>3</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>30</VALUE></ROW>
                    </RECORDSET>
                    <RECORDSET>
                        <ROW><VALUE>DDD</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>4</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>40</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>EEE</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>5</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>6</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>FFF</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>7</VALUE></ROW>
                        <ROW><VALUE>70</VALUE></ROW>
                    </RECORDSET>
                 </ROOTELEMENT>";
}

private static void parseXML()
{
    var xmlString = getXML();
    var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
    var values = xml.Descendants("VALUE");
    var groups = values.Select((value, index) => new
    {
        Index = index,
        Value = value
    })
      .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 3)
      .Select(g => new Tuple<XElement, XElement, XElement>(g.ElementAt(0).Value,
                                                           g.ElementAt(1).Value,
                                                           g.ElementAt(2).Value));
}
```